# Is this relative right?

Tags: determiners, relative-pronouns

> Williams went on: "Obviously Their Majesties will be in
>   the Egyptian Apartment." 
>       Fitz nodded. This was
>   the largest suite of rooms. Its wallpaper had decorative motifs from
>   Egyptian temples. 
>       "Mrs. Jevons suggested **which
>   other rooms** should be opened up, and I've wrote it down by
>   here."
>  (Ken Follett, Fall of Giants)

I don’t make out what this phrase ‘which other rooms’ means: 'which' does not seem like a fused relative. And there’s some suspicion that ‘which’ might be the wrong use of ‘whose’ by a character in the novel . What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Which* here acts as a determiner, designating specific members of the set *rooms*. (In traditional grammar it is an adjective.)

Oddly, this use is not specified in OALD, but you'll find it in [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/which). It's not at all uncommon:

> Which method you use depends on your objective.
>   Tell me which dish you want and I will bring it.